# Maven changes plugin not working with Jira cloud

Tags: jira, maven-changes-plugin

I'm trying to use maven changes plugin with jira cloud but in vain.
My pom looks like this :

```
.....
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                ...
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <useJql>true</useJql>
                    <jiraUser>xxxx@gmail.com</jiraUser>
                    <jiraPassword>******</jiraPassword>
                    <webUser>xxxxx@gmail.com</webUser>
                    <webPassword>******</webPassword>
                    <onlyCurrentVersion>true</onlyCurrentVersion>
                    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
                    <smtpPort implementation="java.lang.Integer">465</smtpPort>
                    <username>xxxx@gmail.com</username>
                    <password>*****</password>
                    <toAddresses>
                        <toAddress implementation="java.lang.String">xxxxxx@yahoo.fr</toAddress>
                    </toAddresses>
                    <mailSender>
                        <name>Release Notification</name>
                        <email>xxxx@gmail.com</email>
                    </mailSender>
                    <issueManagementSystems>
                        <issueManagementSystem>JIRA</issueManagementSystem>
                    </issueManagementSystems>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <issueManagement>
        <system>JIRA</system>
        <url>https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/browse/PROJ</url>
    </issueManagement>
....
```

I'm getting a 403 error.

I think that when using jira cloud, I should use a token but I don't know how to configure the plugin with it.

Any help please ?

Comment: What have you tried regarding the token? It will be easier for others to help you if you show what you've tried and what errors you are running in to.

Comment: Thanks @billoverton, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for how to configure to token in the plugin declaration. Actually all I should to do is using the field webPassword to set that token :

```
<webUser>user_email/webUser>
<webPassword>jira_token</webPassword>
```

and delete fields jiraUser and jiraPassword.